# Can I charge a laptop with a solar panel?

Tags: power-supply, solar-energy, interconnect, powerbanks

I have bought a [30W solar panel](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B09LXJZPR1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1), with output:

1. USB 2.0 : 5V/2.4A
2. USB3.0 (QC3.0): 5V/2.4A, 9V/2A, 12V/1.5A
3. DC: 18V/1.66A (Max)

I would like to charge my laptops. I have seen this [power bank of 90 W](https://www.amazon.de/ask/questions/Tx94KE0WBU4BNU?_encoding=UTF8&sort=helpful&ref_=pe_780061_41837241_ans_notf_saa_aas), 24000 mAh and 220V .

- Can I charge the power bank with this solar power or do I need a bigger one?
- What characteristics do I need to look for to choose a solar panel and associated power bank?
- Can I charge the laptop directly with the solar panel?

Comment: The information on the powerbank page, states that it needs to be charged at 16.8V, 2A DC. Can your solar panel deliver that? (Hint: that's a little over 30W so even under optimum conditions that would not achievable). It might charge slower or not at all, nobody can tell except the manufacturer.

Comment: the title question does not match the body question ... `how to charge a laptop?` is not same as `can I charge a power bank?`

Comment: @StarCat I would expect that a power bank *designed for solar charging* at 16.8V 2A would be compatible with a solar panel of 18V 1.66A (max) - noting that the voltage would be below the maximum and that a power bank designed for solar charging would be able to reduce current. If it's *not* designed for solar charging, then it's possible but not guaranteed, and may or may not damage the power bank.

Comment: What power input does your laptop take?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the laptop charging: each laptop has a required input Voltage and input current, it is stated at the bottom of your laptop. For example mine is 20V, 1.6A.

So this (my) laptop needs a input of 20V (no more no less, maybe 19.5 to 21V range is good enough), and a current of at least capable of delivering 1.6A. The manufacturer's charger that came with the laptop can deliver 3.25A, so ideally this should be the current capability of anything else I plug into the laptop.

If I use a solar panel to charge my laptop I need to make sure:

1. Does the voltage output from the solar panel pass through a circuit that drops/boosts the voltage to 20V? DO NOT plug the solar panel directly to the laptop no matter what.
   If it does pass through a special circuit, what is the ripple voltage? this is really important, if the ripple is high enough it will slowly kill your laptop, short capacitors, produce EMI issues between components etc.
2. Voltage output is ALWAYS 20V. If the solar panel cannot provide the 20V, then it should provide 0V and 0V only. Not 15V, not 18V! (or undervoltage issues might occur!).
3. Current capability of the solar panel (aka output of the special circuit) is 3.25A or more. If this is not possible for the solar panel and its circuit, then you can do one the the below:

a) Charge a power bank first (power bank should not have so strict current issues, but make sure that voltage is within range that the power bank can appect), that can deliver 3.25A, and then charge your laptop with the power bank.

b) If the current capability of the solar panel is above the requirement of the laptop (for my case if its >1.6A), then you can use the solar panel's circuit on the laptop, but not to charge it, this will need alot of current. Try to keep the battery charged to 100% and do small tasks on the laptop (not gaming etc) to only draw current for the tasks, not for charging the battery and not for gaming.

Last but not least, the power cable that plugs into your laptop should be short (try to keep it 1-2meters max, the shorter the better) because there will be voltage drop from the solar panel's circuit to your laptop (can be 2V or more. the more current you draw the more the voltage drop)

Also, there should be a visible (to you) current and voltage output from the solar panels's circuit so that you know everything work good (voltage and current are within ranges)

Comment: Running a laptop directly with a solar panel is tough -- although it should be the final aim. So I am planning at charging power banks and then recharge the laptop. The output of the 30W panel is 18 V, 1.6A at full power. The power bank I am looking has an input of AC 100 - 240 V. A 90 W panel (https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B09SG7WH9P/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=A1MYF1292FP6VF&psc=1) with a MC output: 22V 4A would work? Thus, does it make sense to charge laptops with solar panels? Or are they good only for mobiles? Is it work to spend in more powerful panels?

Comment: PS: would a power supply like those of the desktop computers allow to use a laptop directly with the solar power?

Comment: @Gigiux I would say it's possible but you are on your own and you will void your warranty. I would avoid it, simply because laptops are expensive. If you are willing to risk breaking your laptop, and the voltage is close enough, you can try it.

Comment: @Gigiux and since you didn't specify the power input on your laptop, I won't even speculate on whether *your* laptop will work with *your* solar panel.

Comment: The point is that I have several laptops. The largest has an input of 19V, 2.37A, 45W. Since the power bank provides an output of 22V, 4A, the idea is to charge the power bank, then charge the laptop from the power bank.